# System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.at System.Number.StringToNumber

Tags: c#

```
public void GenerateLua()
        {
            _list = new List<string>();

            _list.Add("");

            Structs.Child parentObj = null;

            if(_root.document.children.Count > 1)
            {
                _list.Add("-- REMOVE ALL GROUPING IN YOUR PROJECT TO CONTINUE!!!");
                return;
            }

            //Get parent window size
            foreach(var el in _root.document.children[0].children)
            {
                if(el == null) 
                    continue;

                if(el.name.Equals(_parent))
                {
                    parentObj = el;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (parentObj == null)
            {
                _list.Add("-- CAN'T FIND THE PARENT ELEMENT, TRY AGAIN!");
                return;
            }

            if(parentObj.absoluteBoundingBox == null)
            {
                _list.Add("-- YOUR BACKGROUND IS INVALID, PLEASE SELECT THE MOST DEEP IMAGE");
                return;
            }

            double width, height;
            if (double.TryParse(parentObj.absoluteBoundingBox.width.ToString(), out width)
                && double.TryParse(parentObj.absoluteBoundingBox.height.ToString(), out height))
            {
                _list.Add($"function sw(value)\n    return sx*value/{width}    \nend\n            \nfunction sh(value)    \n    return sy*value/{height}\nend");
            }
            else
            {
                _list.Add("-- WIDTH OR HEIGHT IS NULL OR IN INVALID FORMAT, PLEASE CHECK YOUR ELEMENTS");
            }
            //_list.Add("local x, y = (sW/resW), (sH/resH)");
            _list.Add("");
            _list.Add("function on()");
            foreach(var el in _root.document.children[0].children)
            {
                if (el == null) 
                    continue;

                if (el.name.Equals(_parent))
                    continue;

                var elType = el.type;

                if(elType.Equals("RECTANGLE"))
                {
                    if (el.fills[0].type.Equals("IMAGE"))
                    {
                        double opacity = 1.0f;

                        if (el.fills[0].opacity != null)
                            opacity = el.fills[0].opacity.GetValueOrDefault();
                        else
                            opacity = 1.0f;
                        //Console.WriteLine("test {0}",el.absoluteBoundingBox);
                        if (el.absoluteBoundingBox == null)
                        {
                            
                                _list.Add("   -- ELEMENT jakis IS INVALID, PLEASE CONFIGURE IT PROPERLY");
                                continue;
                            
                           
                        }

                        int val_0 = int.Parse(el.absoluteBoundingBox.x.ToString());
                        int val_1 = int.Parse(el.absoluteBoundingBox.y.ToString());
                        int val_2 = int.Parse(el.absoluteBoundingBox.width.ToString());
                        int val_3 = int.Parse(el.absoluteBoundingBox.height.ToString());
```

Hey, please help. I don't know what's going on with this error, I've lost an hour or more of time and it's beyond me, but for someone it will probably be easy

Throws an error
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
...

[err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad41L.png)

`_list.Add(string.Format("   -- ELEMENT jakis IS INVALID, PLEASE CONFIGURE IT PROPERLY"));`

this line has an error, I removed **"string.Format"** from it and it still throws errors regarding "string"...

Comment: You've literally been told that the input string is not in the correct format but you have chosen not to tell us what the input string was. Have you even looked? That should be the obvious first step. What is the value it's choking on? Where did that value come from? Why is it wrong? Is it reasonable that it could be wrong? You need to debug your code and tell us what you found. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn now.

Comment: Why do you have code like `parentObj.absoluteBoundingBox.width.ToString()`? (And similar code that uses `Parse` rather than `TryParse `?)  What's the type of `parentObj.absoluteBoundingBox.width`? I'm guessing that it's numeric. If it's not, why not?

Comment: @jmcilhinney for me it is also obvious, but for me the debugger here is not transparent, I attached an attachment with "Error details" but there is so much unnecessary information that I don't know what format it returned to be able to fix it

Comment: The exception tells you exactly what line it was thrown on. You can place a breakpoint on that line and then look at the data being used before it's used. That's basic debugging practice, which is why you need to learn how to debug. Most C# tutorials are going to tell you how to write code, not how to find and fix errors in code. That's a separate topic that you need to research separately. Unfortunately, even many courses don't teach proper debugging techniques, which is a gross oversight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible fix is to make an if statement checking if it is not an int.
This is an example on how you can achieve it:

```
if (!int.TryParse(el.absoluteBoundingBox.x.ToString(), out int val_0) ||
    !int.TryParse(el.absoluteBoundingBox.y.ToString(), out int val_1) ||
    !int.TryParse(el.absoluteBoundingBox.width.ToString(), out int val_2) ||
    !int.TryParse(el.absoluteBoundingBox.height.ToString(), out int val_3))
{
    _list.Add("   -- Invalid dimensions, please check configuration");
    continue;
}
```

I hope this helps you solve your problem :)

Comment: I really thank you very much because this is beyond me <3